# How to build gtest framework for QNX Neutrino

Tags: ubuntu, vmware

I have a QNX Neutrino RTOS running in VMware and installed Momentics and other required libraries in Ubuntu 16.04 running in virtual box. 
I am able to compile programs in momentics IDE and able to run them on the target machine (QNX Neutrino). 
I have to install gtest library in the target for developing gtest based test cases. But i dont know how to do. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: From your answer, it looks like the question is on-topic because it deals with installing software on a computer.  Everything else about it is off-topic (installing software on the target device and anything you do on that device, development, etc.).  Without the answer, the question looks off-topic.  I replaced the off-topic tags, but you might want to tweak the question to make it more clearly on-topic.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do it. The gtest shared library files are already available along with the QNX Software Developement Platform.
The path is "/home/user/qnx700/target/qnx7/x86_64/usr/lib" in case of SDP version 7.0 and x86_64 target. Just copy libgtest* files to "/usr/lib/" folder of target.
Everything works fine after that.